# How to change language specific plugins in vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc, autoindent

I'm writing an `SML` program and I'm trying to change the size of indents.  If I add the following to my `.vimrc` file

```
set tabstop=8
set shiftwidth=8
set expandtab
```

It is not reflected in my actual files.  I know this because when I open a `.sml` file and type `:set` it reveals that `shiftwidth=2`

I believe that vim is using a `sml` plugin because my `.vimrc` file (similar to the default one) has the following:

```
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on
```

First off, **What does if has ("autocmd") mean?** And second **How can I adjust the default indent size for .sml files?**  Where might I be able to find this plugin (if this indeed is the issue?  I still want to keep the rest of the sml plugin's features.

Answer (score 2):

`autocmd`s are special commands triggered on specific events or on specific filetypes. They are often used to set options or define mappings that make sense in one language but not in others.

Since `autocmd`s are widely used for filetype specific stuff, `if has("autocmd")` is a way to test if the `autocmd` feature is available and that we can go further without much risk.

The right location for storing filetype-specific settings is `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`, so you should write your settings in:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sml.vim
```

This file is sourced by Vim *after* the default ftplugin so you can, for example, change only the value of `tabstop` and keep the other settings.

However, looking at my own Vim runtime (`/usr/share/vim/vim73`) it looks like there's no ftplugin for `sml`. This means that `~/.vim/ftplugin/sml.vim` would be an equally right choice of location. Pick the one you like.

In this file, just add the lines you need:

```
setlocal tabstop=8
setlocal shiftwidth=8
setlocal expandtab
```

and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

Typing `:help autocmd` will tell you what autocmd does.
It essentially means that vim can auto execute commands upon certain events.

You can type `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` to see where vim is storing its system wide plugins.
There will likely be a syntax, indent and ftplugin directory with files that will get autoloaded when an appropriate matching filetype is loaded.

Alternatively these files will be in the same directories underneath your ~/.vim directory